# How to dynamically create a POST request using CURL?

Tags: php, html, curl

I scraped a website using the simple DOM php parser :

```
<?php
include 'domparse.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://oceanofgames.com/rebel-galaxy-free-download/');
foreach($html->find('form[action="http://oceanofgames.com/Cloud-VPS-Download.php"]') as $element) 
    echo $element;
?>
```

And I ended up with something like :

```
<form action="http://oceanofgames.com/Cloud-VPS-Download.php" target="_blank" method="post"> 
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="Rebel_Galaxy.zip" /><br /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="filesize" value="2GB" /><br /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="85.25.103.44" />
  </p> 
  <div align="center"> 
    <input type="image" alt="Download" height="99" src="http://oceanofgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/button-download.png" width="184" /> 
  </div> 
</form>
```

I need to make a POST server to the server using these credentials of the form using CURL and I have no idea how to do it. Please guide me.

I know that the manual way of doing it is :

```
curl --data "filename=Rebel_Galaxy.zip&filesize=2GB&id=85.25" https://example.com/resource
```

But, I have a lot of such URL's to process. How do I write a php code to isolate each of those elements and then make a POST request using CURL?

I am new to PHP, so it would be really appreciated if you could keep it simple :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Simplest way to use POST in CURL would be:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/resource';
$data = 'filename=Rebel_Galaxy.zip&filesize=2GB&id=85.25';

$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
/*curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0'
    )
);*/   

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

echo  $server_output;
```

Comment: I understand this part. The problem is the $data you are talking about has to be dynamically generated from the html form above. How do I do that?

Comment: Okay! For that you can use regex or DOM Element! For example, I am assuming that you have the input names, So you will need the input value only, right? For example: input.*?name="filename"\s*value="(.*?)"